# self.nextResponder vs super for touchesMoved

Tags: ios, events, touch

Here's the setup.

I have a custom UIScrollView as a subview of PrimeView.

The custom UIScrollView can be regarded as overlaid scrollview and it gets all touch events initially.

Now, when the scroll view isn't dragging, I want it to pass touch events to other responders.
Below is my code at present, but I'm not sure about the difference between self.nextResponder and super here.

I don't get why touchesBegan is passed to the superview correctly, but touchesMoved isn't passed to the superview.

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    if (!self.dragging)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event];

    }

    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; //                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's stance is that you should never do something like this:

```
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event];
```

If you do this, you're going outside UIKit's own forwarding of messages up the responder chain, and the result is undefined.

Also, in your `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, you're sending `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to `nextResponder`, which seems suspicious.

Also, in your `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, you're passing on the event twice, which seems like a bad idea.

If you want to handle drags conditionally, your best bet is to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  If the recognizer doesn't accept the event, it will be forwarded up the responder chain normally.

If you are a registered (paid) iOS developer, you should have access to the [WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/).  I **strongly** recommend you watch the “Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views” video.  I won't say more about it because its contents are still under NDA.

Comment: thanks for the valuable response and the link. What do you think about this posting which talks about usability of next.responder? http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.jp/2008/10/bit-about-responder-chain.html

Comment: Watch the video.  Pay attention at 40:45.